# Can atom be both predicate and operator?

Tags: prolog, operators, clause

Is it possible to use atom as both operator and predicate.
Something along the lines :

```
:- op(101, fy, rule).
:- op(99,  xfy, ==>).
rule(R) :- write_canonical(R).
```

So that I can say :

```
 rule ...blah... ==> ...abc..
```

instead of :

```
 rule( ...blah... ==> ...abc.).
```

Comment: Did you try it? It should work if your specify the precedence correctly. For example `2 + 3` and `'+'(2, 3)` evaluate the same way in an `is/2` call.

Comment: hmm.. tried it in isolation , it works... let me try in the bigger prj.

Comment: Interesting resource which explains the case with [arithmetic examples](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lurker said, the problem was resolved when I set correct precedence.

In your specific case it will depend what else you have defined and how do you use it.

To check for conflicting precedence use current_op/3.